# Is it possible set up an endpoint for a model I created in AWS SageMaker without using the SageMaker SDK

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I've created my own model on a AWS SageMaker instance, with my own training and inference loops. I want to deploy it so that I can call the model for inference from AWS Lambda.

I didn't use the SageMaker package to develop at all, but every tutorial (here is [one](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-aws-sagemaker-and-lambda-function-to-build-a-serverless-ml-platform-f14b3ec5854a%3E)) I've looked at does so.

How do I create an endpoint without using the SageMaker package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the boto3 library to do this.

Here is an example of pseudo code for this -

```
import boto3
sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
create_model_respose = sm_client.create_model(ModelName=model_name, ExecutionRoleArn=role, Containers=[container] )

create_endpoint_config_response = sm_client.create_endpoint_config(EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name)

create_endpoint_response = sm_client.create_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name)
```